# Creating Multiple UIImageView using a for loop - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, image, uiimageview

I'm trying to add multiple `UIImageView` to a `scrollView`. The number of imageview differs. This number is read from a file.

So now I have to create **`UIImageView` *imageView1,`UIImageView` *imageView2,`UIImageView` *imageView3 ... `UIImageView` *imageViewN**.

How do I add the number to the end of ***imageView(?)**

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done the way that you are thinking.  What you should do is use a NSMutableArray like so:

```
NSMutableArray *imageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSInteger i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    UIImageView *currentImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((0 * (110 * i)), 0, 100, 100)];
    [currentImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];
    [imageViews addObject:currentImageView];
}


//To reference the image views just call objectAtIndex
UIImageView *imageView1 = [imageViews objectAtIndex:0];
UIImageView *imageView2 = [imageViews objectAtIndex:1];
```

This also makes your code much more flexible.

Comment: After [imageViews addObject:currentImageView]; add [myScrollView addSubView:imageViews];(optional) and  [imageViews release]; if you don't use ARC

Answer (score 0):

Add to above code fragment:

```
 NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat@"test_%d.png", i];
 [currentImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
```

thus you can add UIImageViews with different images

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still search for this topics recently, this is the Swift 3 version to do what @Siddharthan wants:

```
    //you may give any Int value to these variables
    let Xposition = 19
    let Yposition = 19
    let imageWidth = 93
    let imageHeight = 128

    //create UIImageView object
    var curr_imageView = UIImageView()
    for i in 0 ..< images.count {
        if imageViews.isEmpty {
            curr_imageView = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect(x: Xposition, y: Yposition, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight))
        } else {
            curr_imageView = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect(x: Int(imageViews[i-1].frame.origin.x)+Int(imageViews[i-1].frame.size.width), y: Yposition, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight))
        }

        curr_imageView.image = UIImage(named: images[i])
        curr_imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.scrollView1.addSubview(curr_imageView)
        imageViews.append(curr_imageView)
    }

    self.scrollView1.contentSize = CGSize(width: imageViews[imageViews.count-1].frame.size.width+imageViews[imageViews.count-1].frame.origin.x+CGFloat(Xposition), height: self.scrollView1.frame.size.height)
```